# VSCode code autocomplete behavior

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed that VSCode uses only the files that are opened in editors (tabs) for looking up names for code auto complete. It is strange for me. To my mind the more usual behavior is to look up all files in opened folder, but not use only the opened files. Is this behavior by design ?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: I use JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, to consider the opened folder as JS project, the "jsconfig.json" is required. Read more [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a `jsconfig.json` file at the root of your workspace:

```
{
   "exclude": [
     "node_modules" 
   ]
}
```

This tells VSCode to treat all JS files in your workspace as part of a single project, even if the files have not been opened yet. You can find more information about `jsconfig.json` files [in our documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson)

Comment: Yes, it works. But it works even with empty jsconfig.json. Maybe the "allowJS" attribute is required for it - as mentioned at the page you provided in the comment above, the file implicitly contains the attribute.