# Autocomplete for the require statement in VS Code

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense, require

I can't find anything straight and to the point on why VS Code's intellisense doesn't show a suggestion for the `require()` statement. E.g. `const EventEmitter = require('events');` Why is it that `require()` doesn't appear in intellisense? I've looked at the `settings.json` file and tried a number of VS Code extensions, but can't get this to work. What am I leaving out?

Comment: read the answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358842/vscode-code-autocomplete-behavior